# US Citizenship Revocation/Denaturalization - How does this compare with other countries?

Tags: united-states, immigration, citizenship

Recently I read about president Trump forming a task force to find and remove the citizenship of anyone who lied to obtain citizenship in the united states:

[Article Here](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/justice-department/trump-administration-launches-bid-catch-citizenship-cheaters-n882166)

I'm wondering if the process of denaturalization is the same in other countries? If not then which countries have such a process, and which do not, and more importantly(without delving too much into the history of each country) why?

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, if you convinced the government through lies to give you a paper claiming that you have citizenship, then you don't actually have citizenship. So if the lies are found out, then you never had citizenship. Your citizenship isn't taken away, because you never had it in the first place. Your papers will be taken away, and all the advantages you had because it was *believed* that you have citizenship are taken away.

If you *really* have gained citizenship, then in the UK it is very, very hard to take it away from you, and there are not many cases. But what Trump is talking about would legally not be "taking someone's citizenship away" but "correcting incorrect facts".

Comment: can you give some case law or examples of people being stripped of their passport in the situation described in the first paragraph?

Comment: Interesting and I agree in the reasoning behind the logic, however I'm more interested in president outside of the western world, how does the US policy compare with countries such as China, Brazil, or Ethiopia? Is the denationalization process only something that's isolated to the west or is it present in every country?